# jQuery plugin extend order

Tags: javascript, jquery, design-patterns, jquery-plugins, jquery-boilerplate

I'm writing a jQuery plugin using [A Highly Configurable And Mutable Plugin Pattern](https://github.com/jquery-boilerplate/jquery-patterns/blob/master/patterns/jquery.highly-configurable.plugin.boilerplate.js) (Until now I've nevere created a "complete" jQuery plugin with these design patterns)

Now, I'd like to create a plugin where the options can be extended as data attributes like:

```
<div class="my-wrapper" data-option="myoption" [...]>
```

or as a collection like:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.my-wrapper').myPlugin({
        option: 'another option',
        [...]
    });
});
```

as you can see, this is a little different configuration as the one described [here](https://addyosmani.com/resources/essentialjsdesignpatterns/book/#jquerypluginpatterns) (you have to scroll down a little to find the pattern I'm using)
This is the `$.extend` code line:

```
$.extend( {}, this.defaults, this.options, this.metadata );
```

But what happens if `data-option` is missing? well simply `option === undefined` because I'm declaring `this.metadata` as

```
this.metadata: {
    option: this.$element.data('option')
}
```

How can I avoid this?

Should I "check" `this.metadata` in order to remove the undefined attributes or simply change the `$.extend` line to

```
$.extend( {}, this.defaults, this.metadata, this.options );
```

Or, for example, throw an exception like "option is missing"? I think there may be too many answer to this question, but I simply want to avoid that a "default" option is missing or undefined if the user does not set it as a data attribute.

Thanks everyone!

Comment: You say to set `default: {option : this.$element.data('option') === undefined ? this.$element.data('option') : 'myDefault' }` ?

Comment: Not like that. Set the default options.